# How to abandon or cancel std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdthread

I am using std::threads to implement a producer, which does some long time computation, but the code used, does not provide an abort method. But I need the calling thread to move on immediately after an abort was requested.
So I tried to just abandon the thread by calling detach(). The idea is that the thread completes the computation, but the result is discarded:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>

class C
{
public:
    void spawn()
    {
        t1.swap(std::thread(&C::producer, this, 1));
    }


    void abort()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mx);
        aborted = true;
        t1.detach();
    }

    bool tryGetResult(int &result)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mx);
        if (!q.empty()) {
            result = q.front();
            q.pop();
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

private:
    std::thread t1;
    std::mutex mx;
    std::queue<int> q;
    bool aborted = false;

    void producer(int id)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mx);
            if (aborted) break;
            q.push(id * 10 + i);
            i++;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        C c;
        c.spawn();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));
        c.abort();
    }

    std::cout << "Done...";
    std::cin.get();
}
```

This approach appears to work, but for me it smells.
I don't understand why the thread does not cause an access violation, because it tries to access the object after it has been destroyed.

Is there a way to inform the thread that it has been detached and must exit without accessing any class member.

Comment: Why do you believe it is accessing something after the object has been destroyed?

Comment: Access the object after it has been deleted is UB, and one of it's possible manifestation is that the program appears to work as expected.

Comment: @NathanOliver it can. `C` is destructed in the main thread after exiting the scope, there is nothing which guarantees that producer will exit before this.

Comment: "*I don't understand why the thread does not cause an access violation*" - undefined behavior, anything could happen

Comment: @DanM. It most certainly cannot. `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mx);` stops code from moving up.

Comment: @NathanOliver you are right of course.

Comment: Forcibly killing (canceling) a thread is a *really* bad idea. Threads all share the same address space of the creating process, so if one just dies you have no idea what the state of your address space is. Either wait for threads to terminate by `join()`ing them, or send them a signal that they should exit through some `atomic` or `mutex` protected variable that they have been written to check regularly. Also read up on "condition variables". In short: don't cancel/kill threads. Ask them kindly to exit and write them to do so. Then `join` them to know they have done so.

Comment: @SergeyA You are correct.  I missed `abort` called `detach`, not `join`.

Comment: This code smell like own implementation of `std::future` and `std::promise` or `std::packaged_task`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> t1.swap(std::thread(&C::producer, this, 1));
> ```

The above is ill-formed, because `std::thread::swap` is declared:

```
void swap( thread& other ) noexcept;
```

`std::thread(&C::producer, this, 1)` is a temporary, and thus an rvalue. It cannot be bound to the non-const lvalue reference of `swap`.

Perhaps you inteded to write `t1 = std::thread(&C::producer, this, 1);` instead.

---

> I don't understand why the thread does not cause an access violation

The behaviour of accessing an object outside of its lifetime is undefined. It is not guaranteed to cause an access violation.

> Is this OK

No.

> or is there a better way to implement something like this?

The ideal solution depends on the case.

A simple solution is to use a stateful callable to create the thread, and store a shared pointer to the shared state. It will be kept alive by whoever lives longer. This can have performance implications if the state is accessed often.

Even simpler solution is to use static storage for the shared state. This doesn't have the potential performance issues that shared pointer may have, but there are other problems with global state.

Comment: @SergeyA he could be compiling with MSVC extension that allows this enabled or ignoring warnings, but it's not a great idea either way.

Comment: @SergeyA It *is* a compilation error in GCC at least. That said, compilers are allowed to not fail compilation of ill-formed program. They are not required to fail.

Comment: @SergeyA To be fair, MSVC is not alone in this, GCC has a fair share of GNU-isms and this specific case is a compilation error on new projects created starting from VS2017 if not 2015 (where permissive- flag was introduced).

Comment: A shared pointer does the job: answer accepted. I will also post a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You thread clearly accesses data after your class C is destroyed. This is undefined behaviour so **don't rely in this**.

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to terminate the thread before you exit your program. This is inherently unsafe since you have no idea what memory the thread is accessing when you terminate it and chances are your program will be left in a bad state.

The only correct what to terminate your thread is get the thread itself the shut down. You are already doing this in your abort function. This sets the `aborted` variable to `true` which in turn will break you our of the threads loop and exit your thread function.

But rather than detach which is what you are doing you should rather join the thread. This will make your main thread wait until your worker thread had terminated before you resume. After this it is safe to delete C.

Comment: Assume that the computation within the thread takes some time and can not be cancelled (3rd party library). So using join() will block the calling thread for too long a time.

Comment: Then you must either terminate the entire process and let the OS do the cleanup for you or take the hit and wait. What you cannot do is just terminate the thread.

Comment: You could launch the 3rd party library within another process and the communicate with it via some IPC mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the accepted answer, a shared_ptr can provide the required behavior.
In the abort-case, the shared_ptr lives just as long as the last  abandoned thread.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>

class C
{
public:
    ~C()
    {
        std::cout << "Dtor\n";
    }


    void abort()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mx);
        aborted = true;
    }

    std::mutex mx;
    std::queue<int> q;
    bool aborted = false;

    static void staticProducer(std::shared_ptr<C> arg, int id)
    {
        arg->producer(id);
    }

    void producer(int id)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i<300000) {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(mx);
            if (aborted) break;
            q.push(id * 10 + i);
            i++;
            std::cout << "Push\n";
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        std::shared_ptr<C> c = std::make_shared<C>();
        std::thread t1 = std::thread(&C::staticProducer, c, 1);

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(2000));

        // scenario 1: abort
        c->abort();
        t1.detach();

        // scenario 2: wait for completion and get result
        // t1.join();
        // std::cout << c->q.size() << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "Done...";
    std::cin.get();
}
```